# SQL - Getting the Min value

Tags: sql

Can someone help me with the below query. Thank you very much!

I'm trying to get from this:

```
FILE_NO     EVENT_TIME           VOY
VN1234      2021-06-20 03:15:00  QR888/20
VN1234      2021-06-22 07:10:00  QR999/22
```

To this:

```
FILE_NO     EVENT_TIME           VOY
VN1234      2021-06-20 03:15:00  QR888/20
```

My query is:

```
SELECT
        BEE.FILE_NO,
        BEE.TIME,
        BEE.VOY
FROM    BRDB.EXPORT_EVENT BEE
WHERE   
        BEE.EVENT_CODE = 'OKL' AND
        BEE.FILE_NO = 'VN1234'
```

Comment: Please explain the logic for your query.  And tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Are you expecting the results based on `MIN(EVENT_TIME)` of the `FILE_NO`?

Comment: Arulkumar

Yes. but because there is the VOY information that I need to collect as well. this VOY element prevent me from using the MIN and GROUP BY

Comment: What should happen when two (or more) records have the same EVENT_TIME ?

Comment: Luuk - It won't happen this case under my current system. There are 2 records because there are differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `order by` and limit the rows to one row:

```
SELECT BEE.*
FROM BRDB.EXPORT_EVENT BEE
WHERE BEE.EVENT_CODE = 'OKL' AND
      BEE.FILE_NO = 'VN1234'
ORDER BY EVENT_TIME
OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Note:  This uses standard SQL syntax.  Most databases have an alternative method for limiting the result set to one row -- such as `LIMIT` or `SELECT TOP`.

EDIT:

Based on the edit:

```
SELECT BEE.*
FROM (SELECT BEE.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BEE.FILE_NO ORDER BY EVENT_TIME ASC) as seqnum
      FROM BRDB.EXPORT_EVENT BEE
      WHERE BEE.EVENT_CODE = 'OKL' 
     ) BEE
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,
Thank you. I'm using the BEE.FILE_NO = 'VN1234' clause for example purpose only, my query should have more records other than VN1234. Using FETCH FIRST might not work.

Comment: @TonyNguyen . . . I edited the answer.  In the future, you should be more careful about your questions and accurately describe your intentions.